# How to to avoid a background image from automatically creating a scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I've been going crazy these past couple of days trying to figure out a way to fix this.

My issue: I want to have a column part(let's say 10%) at the right of an basic one page site(no scroll bar)

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/498v5reh/

```
#sidecolor {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/b9/78/50/b97850a4460e7a80600a3e0eb6b1bc4d.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 100% 10%;
}
```

But when I add the background-image to the column, since the image is larger it expands through the column creating a scroll bar.

Is it possible to have the image cropped depending on the viewer's screen size so there's no scroll bar at all?

Thanks

Comment: the problem is the padding: 100% on top and bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong approach.
If you want a fixed column on the right use the position absolute:

```
#sidecolor {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color (...);
    padding: 10% 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Another problem is the padding. Don't use the 100%, and I have used the box-sizing: border-box so that the padding does not change the height.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/498v5reh/15/

Answer (score 1):

So you want it fixed.

Add the following CSS to your #sidecolor. And clean up.

```
#sidecolor {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(247, 233, 233);
  color: black;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro, monospace;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#maintext {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 20% 0 0 20%;
  position: absolute;
}

#sidecolor {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/b9/78/50/b97850a4460e7a80600a3e0eb6b1bc4d.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 100% 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="site">
  <div id="sidecolor">

  </div>

  <div id="maintext">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidecolor {
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/b9/78/50       /b97850a4460e7a80600a3e0eb6b1bc4d.jpg");
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.